# Adding current item id into db in sitecore

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6, sqlclient

I have ProductID column in my db and I want to add current item id to this column. I've tryed this, but it doesn't work:

```
private void InsertInfo()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        string sql = "INSERT INTO CommentsTable (Name, Email, Comment, ProductID) VALUES (@Name,@Email,@Comment,@ProductID)";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Any exception or error message?

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: On which line? Please debug your code.

Comment: var currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Request.QueryString["id"])

Comment: Either Context, Database, Request or QueryString is null or Id is not a key in QueryString

Comment: Please debug you code and tell us in which line you got exception.

Comment: I've changed my code(above) and now I have this exception: System.Exception: Insert Error:The parameterized query '(@Name nvarchar(6),@Email nvarchar(13),@Comment nvarchar(19),@Pr' expects the parameter '@ProductID', which was not supplied.

Comment: So maybe here is null 'Request.QueryString["id"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the ID of the product you're currently browsing you can just use: `Sitecore.Context.Item.ID`. If you can't use that, you'll have to make sure that your querystring actually exists and has a value. With Sitecore you can use: `Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetQueryString("id", string.Empty)` where the `string.Empty` can be replaced with whatever you want the default value to be.

Comment: I've tried Sitecore.Context.Item.ID (code above), but the exception appeared:  System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type Sitecore.Data.ID to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: You might want to use Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString() then. The ID is a GUID though, so it depends on the format you're trying to save it into your table.

Comment: I'd say you'd have to double-check your CommentsTable definition to make sure you don't have any typos in the ProductID column then - that's what the error sounds like...

Comment: it works fine(when you browse this project in browser), but it doesn't work in a custom editor tab(in sitecore content editor). I've created a custom editor tab in content editor and in URL chose aspx layout with the same code. And in a tab it displays exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I guess in content editor, sitecore doesn't understand what "Sitecore.Context.Item.ID" is. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you passing an ID in the querystring? If so use Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetQueryString("id", string.Empty) instead of Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.

Comment: no, I'm not passing an ID in the querystring. I'm using it just to add id value into db, as a parameter: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString()); (code above)

Comment: How do you define your custom editor tab? Is that a button in the Content Editor, or is it to do with your custom (aspx) application? What is the code behind there? How did you define it in the Core database? (It would probably be useful to update your question with these details)